# spring boot rabbitMQ DLE not accepting any messages

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

I am working on spring-boot rabbitMQ. I am creating a dead letter queue which i can able to see in RabbitMQ admin as "D,DLE" but no DLK might be i am missing setting "x-dead-letter-routing-key", the thing is i don't want routing key.Few of my consumers are binding to a particular exchange and i am creating DLE per exchange if there is any issue in a consumer for that exchange then DLE attached to that exchange which receive that message and do a user dependent logic.But unfortunately this is not working, the DLE isn't receiving any message.

Please find the code below,

```
package com.sample.rabbit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Argument;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.QueueBinding;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultClassMapper;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleRabbitApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SampleRabbitApplication.class, args);
    context.getBean(SampleRabbitApplication.class).runDemo();
    context.close();
}

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate template;

private void runDemo() throws Exception {
    this.template.convertAndSend("sample-queue", new Foo("bar"),m -> {
        m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("__TypeId__","foo");
        return m;
    });

    this.template.convertAndSend("sample-queue", new Foo("throw"),m -> {
        m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("__TypeId__","foo");
        return m;
    });
    this.template.convertAndSend("sample-queue", new Foo("bar"), m -> {
        return new Message("some bad json".getBytes(), m.getMessageProperties());
    });
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

@RabbitListener(
        id = "sample-queue",
        bindings = @QueueBinding(
                value = @org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Queue(value = "sample-queue", durable = "true"),
                exchange = @org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Exchange(value = "sample.exchange", durable = "true")
        )
)
public void handle(Foo in) {
    System.out.println("Received: " + in);
if("throw".equalsIgnoreCase(in.getFoo())){
        throw new BadRequestException("Foo contains throw so it throwed the exception.");
    }
}

@RabbitListener(
        id = "sample-dead-letter-queue",
        bindings = @QueueBinding(
                value = @org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Queue(value = "sample-dead-letter-queue", durable = "true", arguments = {@Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-exchange",value = "sample.exchange"),@Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-routing-key",value = "#")}),
                exchange = @org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Exchange(value = "critical.exchange", durable = "true",type = "topic")
        )
)
public void handleDLE(Message in) {
    System.out.println("Received in DLE: " + in.getBody());
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter());
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(new MyFatalExceptionStrategy());
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonConverter() {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    DefaultClassMapper mapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    mapper.setDefaultType(Foo.class);
    converter.setClassMapper(mapper);
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

public static class MyFatalExceptionStrategy extends ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy {

    private final Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public boolean isFatal(Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof ListenerExecutionFailedException && isCauseFatal(t.getCause())) {
            //To do : Here we have to configure DLE(Critical queue) and put all the messages in the critical queue.
            ListenerExecutionFailedException lefe = (ListenerExecutionFailedException) t;
            if(lefe.getFailedMessage() != null) {
                LOG.info("Failed to process inbound message from queue "
                        + lefe.getFailedMessage().getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue()
                        + "; failed message: " + lefe.getFailedMessage(), t);
            } else {
                LOG.info("Failed to process inbound message from queue "
                        + lefe.getMessage(), t);
            }
        }
        return super.isFatal(t);
    }

    private boolean isCauseFatal(Throwable cause) {
        return cause instanceof MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentNotValidException
                || cause instanceof MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException
                || cause instanceof NoSuchMethodException
                || cause instanceof ClassCastException
                || isUserCauseFatal(cause);
    }

    /**
     * Subclasses can override this to add custom exceptions.
     * @param cause the cause
     * @return true if the cause is fatal.
     */
    protected boolean isUserCauseFatal(Throwable cause) {
        return true;
    }


}

public static class Foo {

    private String foo;

    public Foo() {
        super();
    }

    public Foo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [foo=" + this.foo + "]";
    }

}
}
```

My Exchanges and Queue's are Direct,each of my consumer will use different routing key but it belongs to same exchange, So how can i write a DLE which efficiently consume all the failure messages.In the above code sample one message is success and other one failure but i couldn't see the failure message in DLE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure a queue with a dead-letter exchange (DLX) but no dead-letter routing key, the message is routed to the DLX with the original routing key.

The easiest way to handle your use case is to make the DLX a topic exchange and bind a queue to it with routing key `#` (wildcard for all messages) and all errors will go to that queue.

If you want to segregate the errors into individual queues, then bind a DLQ for each with the original routing key.

**EDIT**

Here is the correct configuration:

```
@RabbitListener(id = "sample-queue",
        bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "sample-queue", durable = "true", arguments =
                        @Argument(name = "x-dead-letter-exchange", value = "critical.exchange")),
                    exchange = @Exchange(value = "sample.exchange", durable = "true")))
public void handle(Foo in) {
    System.out.println("Received: " + in);
}

@RabbitListener(id = "sample-dead-letter-queue", containerFactory = "noJsonContainerFactory",
        bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "sample-dead-letter-queue", durable = "true"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "critical.exchange", durable = "true", type = "topic"),
            key = "#"))
public void handleDLE(Message in) {
    System.out.println("Received in DLE: " + new String(in.getBody()));
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory noJsonContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: @Gary.Thanks a lot for your reply.I have tried as per your answer but it couldn't work for me,Still i couldn't get the failure message.Could you please check my code, My DLE exchange is using a separate exchange which is topic and the actual consumer is using different exchange(Direct) is it fine ? I am getting "MessageConversionException" and it enters "isFatal"  section in "ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler" but i couldn't get that message inside DLE. Please guide me to resolve this isse.

Comment: You have the dead letter configuration wrong. It needs to go on the original queue. Also, you can't use the same converter to receive from the DLQ; see my edit.

Comment: Yes now it enters DLE but in rabbitMQ admin page Dead letter queue is not marked with DKX,DLK instead consumer queue is marked with DLX this is not an issue ?

Comment: Also i found one more issue...If i am throwing any custom exception from my consumer it is restarting the consumer again and again, Those messages are not coming into DLE consumer.I set the following property  "spring.rabbitmq.listener.default-requeue-rejected=false" in application.properties but no use.

Comment: > `Dead letter queue is not marked with DKX,DLK` That is correct - it's the original queue that is configured to send rejections to the DLX; the DLQ is itself just a regular queue. Your code works fine for me with the above changes - `Received in DLE: some bad json`; `requeueRejected=false` means send to the DLX for __all__ exceptions.

Comment: Please find my updated code in the question.I have followed the following link http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java?a=org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit and in the "isUserFatal" method i have to return true so that it is not requeing the message again,The message will be forwarded to DLQ if there is any custom exception

Comment: As I said, I copied your original code, fixed the queue declarations and the container factory and it works perfectly; you must have broken something else. I am not prepared to keep debugging your code.

Comment: Russel..I have updated the code which will throw custom exception inside the consumer.The custom exception is requeing again and again even after setting the property "spring.rabbitmq.listener.default-requeue-rejected=false" but i can able to resolve this issue by following the link http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java?a=org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit and instead of false i have thrown true in "isUserCauseFatal" is it right ?

Comment: Returning true will cause the message to be rejected. If you turn on DEBUG logging, you should see `Rejecting messages (requeue=false)`.

Comment: Thanks for the debug log information.For me i can able to see "2017-03-08 18:16:28.378 DEBUG 76327 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Rejecting messages (requeue=true)" in DEBUG log.

Comment: I can able to resolve this issue by setting "factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);", some how the properties in application.properties is not working.Now i can able to see Rejecting messages (requeue=false)